# Logic app oracle get rows select query provide alias to columns

Tags: oracle, azure-logic-apps

I need to execute a Oracle query in Logic app. The query has some columns with alias. How do i configure this in Oracle get rows action.

[image]

I checked the [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/oracle/), but i did not find any info on this.

Below is the query i'm trying to execute

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  employee_num EMPLOYEE_ID,
  employee_number  ORAC_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
  DECODE(employee_type,
  'Employee',
  'Employee_ID',
  'Worker_ID') EMPLOYEE_TYPE 
FROM person_stg 
WHERE 
  id_reference IS NULL AND  
  process_flag ='PROCESSED' AND 
  mode_flag ='CREATE' AND 
  employee_number IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a solution which can help us to select from the table with some columns alias. But I can provide a workaround for your reference, you can use "[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action)" action in logic app to implement it. Please refer to my logic app below:

Since I don't have oracle server, so here I use sql server(but I think it doesn't matter).

My table looks like:
[image]

And my logic app show as:
[image]

After running the logic app, we can find the result show as(the columns' name show with new name):
[image]